# Who can use the Asana connection which get created inside out power automate flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have created a scheduled flow, which loop through a SharePoint list items and create Asana tasks, as follow:-

[image: johnjohn123_0-1698799348592.png]

now when  I added the Asana step >> i were asked to login to Asana, so i login using an Asana admin username/password.. so my question is who can reuse this connection? or it will/can only be used inside the current flow? so no one can use this connection to perform actions on Asana on behave of the admin username (without entering the Asana admin username/password)??

Answer (score 2):

The Asana connection created inside the Power Automate flow can only be used by the user who created it, in this case, the Asana admin who logged in to create the connection. No one else can use this connection to perform actions on Asana on behalf of the admin username without entering the Asana admin username/password.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but is there any documentation which confirm this? Thanks